# Librerías de terceros en Artifactory de Azure DevOps no se instalan al ejecutar npm install

Tags: npm, azure, vsts, devops

tengo un artefacto en AzureDevops de NPM. Este tiene una serie de librerías de terceros que se necesitan para que pueda funcionar el artefacto correctamente.

El problema es que al ejecutar NPM INSTALL no se instalan estas librerías necesarias por lo que el artefacto queda inservible.

Mi artefacto tiene la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el package.json tengo las librerías necesarias bien declaradas, dentro de "dependencies" y/o "devDependencies" según proceda.

Si realizo NPM INSTALL no instala nada, me indica en consola "up to date", si uso NPM LIST para ver todos los paquetes, no me aparece ninguno.

¿Alguien se ha enfrentado a este error?

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Conseguí solucionar esto a través de la creación de archivos .npmrc
En este archivo indicas a que registry debe apuntar cada librería.

Pude sacarlo adelante siguiendo la documentación de Microsoft oficial sobre archivos .npmrc

No está muy claro, hay que crear dos archivos, uno dentro del usuario de tu ordenador donde indicas las credenciales de acceso a cada registry y otro a la altura del package.json donde indicas de que registry debe sacar cada librería.

La documentación oficial de Microsoft se encuentra a día de hoy en este link:
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops